# How to get memberof of a built-in group in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I was trying get all the user accounts of a certain group. For that, I used the following filter:

```
BASEDN:  DC=example,DC=com
FILTER:  (&(memberof=CN=Myusers,DC=example,DC=com)(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))
```

which works fine. But I also wanted to get the users for built-in groups such as `Domain Users,Domain Admins` and so on. When I tried using the same type of filter

```
BASEDN:  DC=example,DC=com
FILTER:  (&(memberof=CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com)(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))
```

for these built-in groups, it does not work. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most methods do not reveal membership in the "primary" group.

LDAPWIKI has some LDAP Query Examples for Microsoft Active Directory for all users that have "[Domain Users](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Domain%20Users)" designated as their "primary", search for all users whose primaryGroupID attribute is 513 (by default). The primaryGroupID attribute of the group "Domain Users" is the same integer, 513. The LDAP syntax LDAP SearchFilter could be:

(primaryGroupID=513)

Comment: I have an example of how to do this in C# in an article I wrote: [Active Directory: Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html#the-primary-group)

Comment: @GabrielLuci - Nice work. Love the code and the explanations are helpful.